# Unity3d resize panel with mouse from bottom right corner

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, resize

I want to resize a UI panel with the mouse. I don't know how to do this myself. How can I do this?

Comment: Based on what I know of the Unity UI system...this...is not going to be easy. Almost to the point that I would--in my own project--immediately say it wasn't worth the effort. You'd need to create an unclamped, zero size scroll rect, with no scroll bars that contains your "handle" (the bit you click and drag on). Then based on the handle's position, use `RectTransform.SetSizeWithCurrentAnchors()` to set the panel's new size. You'd have to impose your own restrictions in code to avoid negative sized containers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kind of a short question, so I'm not sure if you want anything extremely specific, but this is something I found on the [Unity Tutorials Website](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/intermediate/live-training-archive/panels-panes-windows). Seems to be what you're looking for:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class ResizePanel : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IDragHandler {

    public Vector2 minSize;
    public Vector2 maxSize;

    private RectTransform rectTransform;
    private Vector2 currentPointerPosition;
    private Vector2 previousPointerPosition;

    void Awake () {
        rectTransform = transform.parent.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
    }

    public void OnPointerDown (PointerEventData data) {
        rectTransform.SetAsLastSibling();
        RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle (rectTransform, data.position, data.pressEventCamera, out previousPointerPosition);
    }

    public void OnDrag (PointerEventData data) {
        if (rectTransform == null)
            return;

        Vector2 sizeDelta = rectTransform.sizeDelta;

        RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle (rectTransform, data.position, data.pressEventCamera, out currentPointerPosition);
        Vector2 resizeValue = currentPointerPosition - previousPointerPosition;

        sizeDelta += new Vector2 (resizeValue.x, -resizeValue.y);
        sizeDelta = new Vector2 (
            Mathf.Clamp (sizeDelta.x, minSize.x, maxSize.x),
            Mathf.Clamp (sizeDelta.y, minSize.y, maxSize.y)
            );

        rectTransform.sizeDelta = sizeDelta;

        previousPointerPosition = currentPointerPosition;
    }
}
```